# Passing parameter to IRuleBuilder extension method

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

This is what I want to do:

```
RuleFor(m => m.User.State).
    StateIsValid(m => m.User.Country);
```

This is how extension method looks like:

```
public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, int?> StateIsValid<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, int?> rule, int country)
    {
        return rule
            .Must(state => IsStateOfCountry(state, country));
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to properly pass the Country parameter or how I should specify country parameter in extension method. 
Using the code above I get compilation error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: It seems fine, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is accessing the "sibling" property `Country` off of the `User`. What if you make the extension method off of the `User` object like this instead?

```
RuleFor(m => m.User).
    StateIsValid();
```

The extension method would then require a constraint:

```
public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<TOuterClass, TUser> StateIsValid<TOuterClass, TUser>(this IRuleBuilder<TOuterClass, TUser> ruleBuilder)
        where TUser : User
    {
        return ruleBuilder
            .Must(user => IsStateOfCountry(user.State, user.Country));
    }

}
```

Comment: It defeats the point of the method if I restrict it only for the User class. I have multiple unrelated classes that have Country/State fields and it wouldn't make sense to have a common interface for those classes.

Comment: The only way the extension method will work like this is to constrain it with a class/interface that exposes the `Country` and `State`. Alternatively, you can make the extension method take in those two values like `IsStateOfCountry` and simply pass those in from the Validation call. Something like this (untested): `RuleFor(m => m.User).Must((m, user) => IsStateOfCountry(user.State, user.Country));`